# Alchemy API relevancy score calculation

Tags: alchemyapi

How are relevance scores determined for AlchemyAPI's extraction of Keywords, Concepts, Entities, etc.?

Are the scores based on frequency of occurrence, placement in the text (title, lead paragraph, etc.), or other factors?